# Cacti - Check plist file

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, cacti, xml, rrdtool

I followed this guide to get Cacti up and running.

http://10100.org/blog/how-to-install-cacti-on-osx-server-109

Everything is good up until I had to create cacti.plist to configure the poller.  In terminal, when i run launchctl it can't find the plist.

```
launchctl: no plist was returned for: /Library/LaunchDaemons/cacti.plist<br>
nothing found to load
```

### cacti.plist xml file

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>cacti</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>php</string>
            <string>/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/cacti/poller.php</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: But the file does exist there? What does `ls /Library/LaunchDaemons/cacti*` say? If the plist you are showing here is this file, you're missing a `<` at the start.

Comment: Yes cacti.plist is in the LaunchDaemons folder.  My guess was that the xml syntax is incorrect like you said.  I copy and pasted from that guide.  I will try your suggestion.

Comment: You the man Yorn.  I can't believe it was the missing bracket at the beginning.

Comment: Heh, didn't think it would be that easy :-) I reposted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `<` at the start of the XML declaration. This makes the file improper XML and therefore an invalid plist file.